# Cannot execute binary file on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

Tags: command-line, permissions, terminal, osx, executable

I want to execute phylocon on a mac OS X lion but after changing the path and making the file executable, I get the error 'cannot execute binary file'. But the steps that I took to running the command worked fine on ubuntu 12.04 which is why i am confused.

command: PhyloCon-v3.linux

http://stormo.wustl.edu/PhyloCon/

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: The command `file PhyloCon-v3.linux` should tell you what it is.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've grabbed [PhyloCon-v3b.linux](http://stormo.wustl.edu/PhyloCon/PhyloCon-v3b.linux) from their web site. That's a Linux executable, it won't run on Mac OS X.

Instead, you need to grab [the source code](http://stormo.wustl.edu/PhyloCon/PhyloCon-v3b.tar.gz) and compile it yourself. Extract the source code into an empty directory, then, if you're lucky, running `make` will compile it.

Note that it doesn't compile cleanly on my Linux box; it appears to use some questionable not-quite-C syntax which my modern GCC is not accepting. It appears easy enough to get to compile, by fixing a few declarations... Whether it works, I'm not at all qualified to answer.